# getting data by id from database after submitting to another page

Tags: php, mysql

I m  trying to get data on another page by id which is on showdetails.php page.but i m unable to please help.

**Showdetails.php**
this page shows details of user with id and button which will allow user to edit details on another page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Details</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
    require('database.php');          
?>

<h1>User Lists</h1>
<?php 
        $select = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM signup";
        $selectdata = $conn->query($select);

        if ($selectdata->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectdata)) {

            $id = $row['id'];
            $first = $row['firstname'];
            $last = $row['lastname']; 

?>
    <form method="get" action="editdetails.php">
        <p><b>ID: <?php echo $id; ?></b></p>
        <p>Name: <?php echo $first; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $last; ?></p>
        <?php 
            $edit = "SELECT id FROM signup WHERE id= '" .$id. "'";
            $selectedit = $conn->query($edit);
        ?>
        <p><input type="submit" name="display" value="Edit Details"></p>
    </form>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**editdetails.php**
On this page, user will be able to edit details, and i want details by id

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit User Details</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
    require('database.php');

    $select = "SELECT firstname, lastname, age, phone_no, age, username, password FROM signup";
    $selectdata = $conn->query($select);

    if ($selectdata->num_rows > 0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectdata); 

            $first = $row['firstname'];
            $last = $row['lastname']; 
            $age = $row['age'];
            $phone_no = $row['phone_no'];
            $username = $row['username'];
            $password = $row['password'];
    }
?>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        # code...       
        $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
        $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
        $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['age']);
        $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['phone_no']);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pass']);

        $update = "UPDATE signup SET firstname= '$first', lastname= '$last', age= '$age', phone_no = '$phone', username = '$username', password = '$password' WHERE id= '$id'";
        $updatedata = $conn->query($update);

        if ($updatedata) {
            # code...
            echo $status = "Details Updated";
        }
        else {
            # code...
            echo $status = "Not Updated";
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        # code...

        $delete = "DELETE FROM signup WHERE firstname = $first";
        $deletedata = $conn->query($delete);

        if ($deletedata) {
            # code...
            echo $status = "Details Deleted";
        }
        else {
            # code...
            echo $status = "Not Deleted";
        }
    }
?>  

    <h1>Edit Details</h1>
    <form method="post" action= "<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>">
    <p>FirstName: <input type="text" name="first" value="<?php echo $first; ?>"></p>
    <p>LastName: <input type="text" name="last" value="<?php echo $last; ?>"></p>
    <p>Phone no: <input type="number" name="phone_no" value="<?php echo $phone_no; ?>"></p>
    <p>Age: <input type="number" name="age" value="<?php echo $age; ?>"></p>
    <p>User: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo $password; ?>"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></p>
    </form>
    <p><?php echo $status; ?></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Thank You.

Comment: No need for a form if you use `GET`, a simple link to `editdetails.php?id=$id` would suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your HTML form a hidden input, like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

Then in your editdetails.php file you can access it with: `$_GET["id"]`.

---

Update:

Add the hidden input to the form in *Showdetails.php*.
Then in *editdetails.php* add at the top of the page `$id = (int)$_GET["id"];`

Then add to your SELECT query in *editdetails.php* a WHERE statement for selecting the correct user:

```
$select = "SELECT ... FROM signup WHERE id = $id";
```

For the update query you are then good to go since you are already using there `WHERE id = $id`. (but before your `$id` variable was not defined)

Comment: Not without changing `method="get"` to `method="post"`

Comment: correct solution, but he uses get in form.. so its $_GET["id"]

Comment: Thank you, haven't notice that

Comment: where should i place $_POST["id"] on that page

Comment: @LincolnMartis I am a bit confused. In your HTML code the update section uses `$_POST` (`if (isset($_POST['update'])) {...`) yet your HTML form is GET. Do you have another form which you haven't showed us?

Comment: @LincolnMartis in your editdetails.php call `$_POST["id"]` or `$_GET["id"]` according to the method used in you form

Comment: it didnt work after i added echo $_POST['id'] on editdetails

Comment: in your update answer i have already added echo $id in show details then why the hidden input

Comment: @LincolnMartis You should put this once in the form. Do what I told you in the update and this should work. (get, not post for the id)